# Overwriting Vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I was trying to overwrite values into my vector:

```
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
  {      
        LJ.clear();
        LJ.reserve(210);

        //Calculate Lennard-Jones potential of every pair
        for(itr = 0; itr < 210; itr++)
        {
            term1 = pow(r[itr], 12);
            term1 = 1/term1;
            term2 = pow(r[itr], 6);
            term2 = 2/term2;
            LJ.push_back(term1 - term2);
        }

        //Calculate the initial Energy in the system Ei
        Ei = accumulate(LJ.begin(), LJ.end(), 0.0);
        Ei = Ei/2;
        cout << Ei << endl;
    }
```

However, whenever I came across the loop twice, the capacity of the vector got some garbage value and when i tried to push an item in, I got a segmentation fault...and if i left our the reserve part, I still got an a seg fault

Comment: You don't need to `reserve` on every iteration of the outer loop, as `vec.clear()` is defined as `vec.erase(vec.begin(), vec.end())`, which does not reduce the capacity. Also, what do you mean with "whenever I came across the loop twice"?

Comment: Show us the code for r and its population.

Comment: What's the definition of `r`?

Comment: Runs fine for me http://codepad.org/vXpHI0Ro

Comment: also, if term2 ever equals 0, you'll get a division by 0 which will likely crash

Comment: Reminds me of this : http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm

Comment: When i = 1, after I execute LJ.clear(), the capacity gets some garbage value, why does that happen?

Comment: @Xeo I know of at least one implementation whose `clear` (correctly or not) deallocates the vector's memory.

Answer (score 4):

> However, whenever I came across the loop twice, the capacity of the vector got some garbage value [...]

This is a clear indication of memory corruption.

You probably have an array on the stack and you are overwriting the stack past the array limit, "stepping" on the vector's toes. Whichever array is closer to the `LJ` declaration is the likely target of an unfortunate write.

Answer (score 1):

If `r` is a `std::vector` too, try changing the inner loop to the following:

```
// assuming r is a vector<double>
for(vector<double>::iterator it = r.begin(), ite = r.end(); it != ite; ++it){
  // use *it instead of r[itr];
  term1 = pow(*it, 12);
  term1 = 1/term1;
  term2 = pow(*it, 6);
  term2 = 2/term2;
  LJ.push_back(term1 - term2);
}
```

However, if `r` is a statically allocated array (i.e., on the stack), change it to this:

```
for(int itr = 0; itr < sizeof(r)/sizeof(r[0]); ++itr){
  // same content...
}
```

If that doesn't segfault, `r` is does *not* have 210 elements.